# Mouse click on array of objects javascript Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, mouseevent, mouseover

I have an array which is full of positions of many different objects in my game and what I'm trying to achieve is when the mouse is on the object in the canvas, the user can click and then a box(will be a menu) will appear.

Here is the code I have already:

```
 this.init_inv = function(value){
    canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
        var x, y;
        for(var i = 0;i < value.length; i++){
            // Get the mouse position relative to the canvas element.
            if (e.layerX || e.layerX) { //for firefox
                x = e.layerX;
                y = e.layerY;
            }
            x-=canvas.offsetLeft;
            y-=canvas.offsetTop;

            if(x>=value[i][0] && x <= (value[i][0] + value[i][2]) &&
               y<=value[i][1]&& y >= (value[i][1]-value[i][2])){
                document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
                inObject=true;
            }
            else{
                document.body.style.cursor = "";
                inObject=false;
            }
        }
    };
    canvas.addEventListener("click", on_click, false);
};
```

The click handler looks like this:

```
function on_click(e) {
    if (inLink)  {
        var dataString = {"save": "true", "level":level, "location_X":pos_X, "location_Y":pos_Y};
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"PHP/class.ajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(success){
                alert("Saved");
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("Not Saved");
            }
        });
    }
    if(inObject){
        console.log("hovering");
    }
}
```

I have a separate click handler because I need to handle clicks at different parts of different canvases.

I believe the problem lies with how I am reading the values in the array, but not sure how. I know this because if I enter an int where the `value[i][0]` etc values are I can click in the area specified and the click triggers and I get the console log.

the array looks like this:

```
var array = [
   [pos_x,pox_y, size]
   //etc...
];
```

Comment: Normally you'd handle this by moving elements around on the canvas and just directly attaching click handlers to them, rather than tracking mousemove and inferring position of a click by looking things up in an array; is there a reason you aren't just leveraging this built-in functionality?

Comment: You may want to look at a library like [KineticJS](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-listen-or-dont-listen-to-events-with-kineticjs/) to help you if you're wanting to react to events on specific items within a canvas.
@ChrisMoschini Canvas doesn't natively allow you to attach event handlers to canvas elements, as everything is rasterized, and the vectors are not retained.

Comment: how do you define the different part of the canvas? the only way i can think of is 1 mouse listener that has 2 different ifs based on location. 1D example: if(x <10) { listener1 } if (x< 20) {listener 2}

Answer (score 0):

so rather than setting `inObject` to true or false, you could set it to false initially, and then set it to `i`, so you know which object was actually selected.

make sure inObject is defined outside of a function so you can access it later.

I will paraphrase your code a bit to do a brief overview of how I would structure this

```
//first of all, name your stuff what it is, rather than array, name it meaningfully
// and since we don't have a huge amount(1000+) of menu items, we can just use them as objects
// arrays are faster, but for clarity purposes, we don't need the speed and might as well have readable code
var menuboxes = [
  {x: 10, y: 10, size: 100},
  {x: 115, y: 10, size: 100}
];

//i suggest using underscore, but this could be converted to a regular each
_.each(menuboxes, function(box, n){
  context.fillRect(box.x, box.y, box.size, box.size);
});

var on_click = function(e){
  // this doesn't change for each item, so define x and y outside of the boxes loop
  x = e.layerX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  y = e.layerY - canvas.offsetTop;
  clickTarget = false
  _.each(menuboxes, function(box, n){
    if(box.x < x && x < box.x + box.size &&
      // no need to invert y, use it like you use x
      box.y < y && y < box.y + box.size) {
        clickTarget = n;
      }
  });
  if(clickTarget !== false){
    openMenu(clickTarget);
  }
};

var openMenu = function(n){
  console.log("You opened box", n, menuboxes[n]);
  // menu opening code here
}

canvas.addEventListener("click", on_click, false);
```

this is untested but should give you some tips.  I suggest using jquery and underscore for now, and eventually coffeescript when you learn the ropes.  Jquery is pretty essential due to browser quirks, underscore is very helpful and fast, and coffeescript is the only way to make readable code in some situations.  copy your code into http://js2coffee.org to see how much shorter it could be.